# In Reactjs , How to set Responsive view for this template?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

[image]

Container is responsive but header,footer and background image is not responsive. How to make that responsive?

Answer (score -1):

Use Front end frameworks like Material-UI or bootstrap, design, etc...then use grid

1. [Bootstrap- grid](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/layout/grid/#responsive-grids)
2. [Material-UI grid](https://mui.com/components/grid/)
3. [Ant Design Grid](https://ant.design/components/grid/)

Answer (score -1):

If you'd rather not use a framework like Shahnad mentioned above, you can use the css property `flex-box`. This [website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) perfectly explains how flex-box works.